# How do you change the discoverable Bluetooth name of a Windows 10 computer?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

By default, the discoverable name of my Windows 10 computer is the same as the computer name.
[image: computer name]
[image: bluetooth name]

How do I change the Bluetooth name without changing the computer name?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Right click on the Start button [image: start button] and choose Device Manager.
   [image]
2. Expand 'Bluetooth' and double click your adapter model. *In my case it's the Marvel Radio Adapter.*
   [image: marvel adapter]
3. Go to the Advanced tab and rename to whatever you desire.
   [image: advanced setting]
4. Click the OK button.  You're done!!
   [image: new bluetooth name]

Comment: Does anyone know a programmatical way to do this? Ideally through PowerShell.